# API Gateway returning 403 - Forbidden

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway with an endpoint that is fulfilled by AWS Lambda proxy integration. I have also configured a custom authorizer for this endpoint. I am seeing an issue where the first request that I make to this endpoint is successful, but additional calls will fail; I get a 403 - Forbidden error. If I wait a while, I can make another request that succeeds but then I start seeing the same problem.

Here's my code for the authorizer:

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

exports.authorizer = async function (event, context) {
  const bearerToken = event.authorizationToken.slice(7);
  const { payload } = jwt.decode(bearerToken);
  return {
    principalId: payload.sub,
    policyDocument: {
      Version: '2012-10-17',
      Statement: [{
        Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
        Effect: 'Allow',
        Resource: event.methodArn,
      }],
    },
  };
};
```

In the API Gateway logs for this endpoint I can see that the authorizer is returning `Allow` but I can still see that the authorization fails:

> (50ac5f87-e152-4933-a797-63d84a528f61) The client is not authorized to perform this operation.

Does anyone know how or why this could happen?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem I think is in the response your authorizer is sending back. In your policy document you can see you are returning `Resource: event.methodArn`.

This would typically work, provided that your authorizer is not caching the response from your custom authorizer (this is on by default). The problem you're experiencing arises when you make a request API Gateway and get back a cached authorizer response that doesn't match the requested ARN of the current request. [This post explains more about how Lambda authorizers work, including caching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html).

You can verify that this is the problem by going into the AWS console and disabling caching for your custom authorizer; once you do this you should no longer experience this problem.

So how can you fix this long term? There's a couple of options:

**Disable caching**: This is the simplest solution. The downside is that you're now invoking your authorizer with every request which will introduce more latency into your API.

**Return a broader policy**: This is the best solution, but more complicated. There's a couple options here, you can return multiple `Allow` policies in your authorizer response that apply to any endpoint that uses this authorizer.

If you look at the [format of an authorizer request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-input.html) you'll see that the `methodArn` is in the following format:

```
{
    "type":"TOKEN",
    "authorizationToken":"{caller-supplied-token}",
    "methodArn":"arn:aws:execute-api:{regionId}:{accountId}:{appId}/{stage}/{httpVerb}/[{resource}/[{child-resources}]]"
}
```

So you're probably returning something like this for the `methodArn`:

```
arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:123456789012:ymy8tbxw7b/*/GET/my-resource/e56bde3c-7c77-46c6-bdf0-ab4a8cb5f5ca
```

A broader policy that would apply to any resource for this endpoint would be:

```
arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:123456789012:ymy8tbxw7b/*/GET/my-resource/*
```

If you have multiple endpoints that use this same authorizer, then you can return multiple policies:

```
{
  "principalId": "user",
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:123456789012:ymy8tbxw7b/*/GET/my-resource/*"
      },
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:123456789012:ymy8tbxw7b/*/POST/my-resource"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I just want to leave one additional tidbit that might help anyone working within AWS's GovCloud. If you are in GovCloud, remember that the arn begins with `arn:aws-us-gov:` and not simply `arn:aws:`. I have an authorizer that gets deployed to both, but I had mistakenly hardcoded `arn:aws:` in the policy the authorizer lambda returns.